# Bind Event To Command And Get Refference To UI Element

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, mvvm-light

What I want to achieve: I want a Command to be triggered when the element has been loaded and I want to get a Refference to this element, so I can Access it in the `MainViewModel.cs`.

What I tried:

I wrote this xaml Code:

```
  <visualizer:PreviewTile DisplayName="Share Tile" TileSize="Wide" Background="Red" IsAnimationEnabled="True" x:Name="P">
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedVisualizer}"></core:InvokeCommandAction>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </visualizer:PreviewTile>
```

And have added this Piece of Code:

```
  private RelayCommand _loadedVisualizerCommand;
  public RelayCommand LoadedVisualizer
    {
        get
        {
            return _loadedVisualizerCommand
                   ?? (_loadedVisualizerCommand = new RelayCommand(
                       async () =>
                       {
                          await new MessageDialog("Loaded", "Some Content").ShowAsync();
                       }));
        }
    }
```

But the Method doesn't get called when the Event Loaded is getting fired.

So I tried this to get a Refference to the Control, but it is throwing a `NullRefference` exception:

In `MainViewModel`:

```
public PreviewTile PreviewTile { get; set; }
```

In `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
 public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();      

        Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            Vm.PreviewTile = P;
        };

    }
```

Despite there are some articles  and questions (some unanswered) about using Events in mvvm light I can't figure out how I can get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can see for this is that the `Page`'s `DataContext` is not correctly set. To use the `MainViewModel` on the page, you have to add it in your `ViewModelLocator` class:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider( () => SimpleIoc.Default );

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel Main => ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
}
```

And then use it on your `MainPage`:

```xml
<Page ...
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">
```

Now the `EventTriggerBehavior` should work as expected.

I have put a [sample project on my GitHub](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2016/tree/master/MvvmLightLoadedCommand) for you to check out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the example Project -  it is working - , idk why someone downvoted this

Comment: Great, happy it helped :-)